# Ponteiro+Struct (DUVIDA)

Tags: ponteiro, struct

Boa tarde pessoal, estou aprendendo a usar ponteiros em `struct`'s... então tentei fazer um exercício de cadastro de `nome` e `id` bem simples com um tamanho do vetor para apenas 3 cadastros.

Não consigo achar o erro do meu código. Quando compilo aparece lixos de memória. Preciso de ajuda!!! Obrigado!
Segue o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char nome[40];
} cadastro;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cadastro v[3], *pv; //uma struct v[3] e um ponteiro para v[3] (pv);
    int i = 0;

    pv = &v[0]; //pv recebe o endereço de v[0];

    while (i < 3) {
        printf("Digite o id:");
        scanf("%d", &pv->id); //pegar o id
        printf("Digite o nome:");
        scanf("%s", &pv->nome); //pegar o nome
        ++pv; //passar pro proximo endereço 
        i++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 3) {
        printf("Id: %d\n", pv->id);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", pv->nome);
        ++pv; //passar pro proximo endereço 
        j++;
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Salve mano. Seu erro está no deslocamento do ponteiro.

Perceba que no fim do while de leitura você avançou o ponteiro 3 casas (número de ciclos do while).

E no while de impressão, novamente você avança o ponteiro, mas note que ele já estava na última posição da alocação quando saiu do laço de cima.

Comment: Então devo retirar os incrementos do ponteiro?

Comment: Quais modificações devo fazer?

Comment: Consegui resolver com sua ajuda amigo! Tudo que precisei fazer foi reiniciar o ponteiro na primeira posição do vetor antes de entrar no segundo While!

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu. Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

```
QUESTÃO RESOLVIDA!

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * 
 */
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char nome[40];
} cadastro;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cadastro v[3], *pv; //uma struct v[3] e um ponteiro para v[3] (pv);
    int i = 0;

    pv = &v[0]; //pv recebe o endereço de v[0];

    while (i < 3) {
        printf("Digite o id:");
        scanf("%d", &pv->id); //pegar o id
        printf("Digite o nome:");
        scanf("%s", &pv->nome); //pegar o nome
        pv++; //passar pro proximo endereço 
        i++;
    }

    int j = 0;

    pv = &v[0];

    while (j < 3) {
        printf("Id: %d\n", pv->id);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", pv->nome);
        pv++; //passar pro proximo endereço 
        j++;
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```